How can I add extra bone with have control when generated?
So I working this first project. and I using metarig. but I have tail behind her. so I wanna know how to add bone with still have control when re-generated? because when I try add bones and re-generated. the tail control didnt show up. also thanks for answer! 

In Metarig open Edit mode and find Samples sub-tab in Rigify UI:

You can find information about samples here
Select sample splines.basic_tail and press Add sample button
Move the created bones in position like this:

You can subdivide bones if you want more bones.
Parent first bone in chain to spline bone using Ctrl+P ⇾ keep offset

Move your bones into the desired collection by pressing M. For example, I moved them into Torso
In Pose mode, select the first bone in the chain, and in the bone tab click on Z button in Rigify type tab:

If you want, you can move generated tweak bones into a separate collection. To do this, activate Assign Tweak Collection, and add one in the list.
Click regenerate and test added controls!

